# Unable to use vedmack/yadcf plugin with tigrang/cakephp-datatable

Tags: jquery, cakephp, datatables-1.10, yadcf

I'm using [tigrang/cakephp-datatable](https://github.com/tigrang/cakephp-datatable) in one of my cakePHP 2.6 projects (and DT 1.10.6). So far, I have been able to successfully implement the plugin with help from the plugin's author. The plugin is excellent and I want' to keep it.

Now, I'm trying to use [vedmack/YADCF](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) plugin along with my existing data table to achieve (especially) column filtering functionality because I find the examples on official DT to be very messy and limited. I keep getting error when I initialise YADCF:

```
TypeError: oTable.settings is not a function
var instance = oTable.settings()[0].oInstance,
```

Is there a way I can get both plugins to work together? Has anyone tried this?

Below is my JS for DT using cakephp-datatable:

```
$('.dataTable').each(function() {
    var table = $(this);
    var model = table.attr('data-config');
    var settings = dataTableSettings[model];
    settings['dom'] = 'lrtip';
    settings['stateSave'] = true;
    settings['stateSaveCallback'] = function (settings, data) {
                $.ajax( {...});
            };
    settings['stateLoadCallback'] = function (settings) {
            ...
            };
    table.dataTable(settings);
});
```

I tried something like this and few other tries after the code above to get YADCF to work but I always got the same error:

```
var table = $('.dataTable');
yadcf.init(table, [
            {column_number: 0, filter_type: "text", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
            ...,
            {column_number: 4, filter_type: "select", filter_default_label: "Select", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
            {column_number: 5, filter_type: "range_number", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
            ...,
        ]);
```

I have tried this YADCF code without the other plugin and it works flawlessly. So, I need help on modifying the code to implement with other plugin.

I also tried this(because DT was initialized using `dataTable()` lowercase "d") but didn't work:

```
$('.dataTable').each(function() {
...
...
table.dataTable(settings)
        .yadcf([
                {column_number: 0, ...},
                ...
            ]);
});
```

**PS:** I had asked the question on the first plugin's github also but I hoped the author of yadcf or someone experienced can help me out here.

Comment: A link to your sample could speed up figuring out what went wrong, b.t.w can you try initializing your tables without the loop? Try init each table by its id selector and see if it works

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks for a quick response. My project is at present hosted on a private server so can't open that project. But I'm in process of creating a sample project on a different server. I'll upload it in about 30 min.

Comment: update me on how it works if you init each table using its id (without the loop)

Comment: @Daniel: you can check a test project here: http://www.alpha.mobotrix.com/cake/users. I checked what you said above and still get same error. BTW, I have just one table, so the loop runs just once.

Comment: Ok, I did a mistake earlier, changed code in wrong file to check without loop. When I don't use loop, it gives me an error stating settings(variable in other plugin) is undefined.

Comment: Instead of the loop and the `var table = $(this);` please init your table like this: `var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable(settings);` yadcf got an open issue regarding the usage of `$(this)` , see https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/96

Comment: Yep. same result as loop. tried `function abc(el) {var table = $(el); ...} abc('.dataTable');`. Note that I have only one table, so using class for selector will not make difference. Moreover, I believe that .each() will also not make a difference because it is looping only once.

Comment: Can we move to chat?

Comment: sorry, can't the thing is that when using `$(this)` it init the table without a selector on which I rely in yadcf later on... , init the table without the loop and without `$(this)` and let me know

Comment: I'm doing it like var `oTable = $('.dataTable');` and then `yadcf.init(oTable, [` so it has nothing to do with `$(this)`.  please check the source on the link i shared.

Comment: can you please check the source on the link. removed loop, replaced `$this` and also used a variable for selector(DT). comments in source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (removed the loop / `this` usage)

```
var table;
var model = table.attr('data-config');
var settings = dataTableSettings[model];
settings['dom'] = 'lrtip';
settings['stateSave'] = true;
settings['stateSaveCallback'] = function (settings, data) {
            // Send an Ajax request to the server with the state object
            $.ajax( {
                "url": "/cake/Users/save_state",
                "data": data,
                "dataType": "json",
                "type": "POST",
                "success": function () {
                    console.log("ca");
                },
            });
        };
settings['stateLoadCallback'] = function (settings) {
        var o;

        // Send an Ajax request to the server to get the data. Note that
        // this is a synchronous request since the data is expected back from the
        // function
            $.ajax( {
                "url": "/cake/Users/get_state",
                "async": false,
                "dataType": "json",
                "success": function (json) {
                o = json;
                },
            });
        return o;
        };
table = $('.dataTable').DataTable(settings);

yadcf.init(table, [
    {column_number: 0, filter_type: "text", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
    {column_number: 1, filter_type: "text", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
    {column_number: 2, filter_type: "text", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
    {column_number: 3, filter_type: "text", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
    {column_number: 4, filter_type: "select", filter_default_label: "Select", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
    {column_number: 5, filter_type: "range_number", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
    {column_number: 6, filter_type: "select", filter_default_label: "Select", filter_reset_button_text: false, filter_delay:500},
]);
```

---

Or you can modify your current code into

`$('.dataTable').DataTable(settings);` **-->** `return $('.dataTable').DataTable(settings);`

`dtable('.dataTable');`  **-->**  `var oTable = dtable('.dataTable');`

Comment: This throws an error for model undefined. check the updated link: http://www.alpha.mobotrix.com/cake/users

Comment: its not the code I suggested, anyway I added some code for replacement of yours, check it out

Comment: Thanks. I resolved using your original post. i just used another variable `var tbl = var tbl = $('.dataTable');` and then changed as `var model = tbl.attr('data-config');` rest all same as your code above. Updated the link for you to check. :) BTW, i had to correct the columns, and it worked. Thanks Daniel for solution and the wonderful YADCF plugin.

Comment: You are wlecome, there were 2 issues, one is that you used `$(this)` and the second is that instead of passing datatables object to yadcf you passed a jquery selector of the table

Comment: seems the issue is not solved completely... the filters appeared but they don't work :( I have commented out stateSave/Load for convenience during testing.

Comment: any chances that my issue is related to https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/1? Asking because it's working (except range filters) if i set `bServerSide: false`

Comment: Not a chance :) have you implemented filtering on your server side? when you filter in your browser a request is being sent to server, look at that request and return the relevant rows only back to your table....

Comment: I think you are right. Was just checking the response myself and realised that returned rows all contain search string in some column or other. it's not happening specific to column. For example if i type "1" in column1 (second col), i get rows that contain 1 in any of the columns instead of just column1. The filters are acting like global filter. Can think of a reason? Further investigation shows that it is searching in columns other than col1

Comment: Done. I take back my comment. It was my mistake that I had set col0 to non searchable in dataTableSettings. Now, I have fixed it. Thanks a lot for all the help and tolerating me.  Again, thanks for awesome YADCF plugin. i mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Feel free to post some php server side code on this thread https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/206 I'm collecting them for other PHP users..

Comment: Sure, will do that over weekend. I'll probably give some instructions for cakephp-datatables users too. I haven't found any post explaining a use of both these awesome plugins together.

Comment: sorry I couldn't find time post my PHP example during weekend. I will write a post as soon as possible, just a bit busy on different project.